# Is it okay to call provider functions in main.dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in Flutter,
I am calling provider functions to load data from database in main.dart and I saw that main.dart is calling them continuously, so I added bool to check if they called or if they are loading now to stop continuous calls, after that it started to concern me. Is this way okay? What is the better way? I don't want to add it to the first pages initstate as if user has details in SharedPreferences, I wait and send token to get different data.

[image]
Here is the calling part in main.dart file.

1. Checks if user has details in SharedPreferences.
2. Loads chats if user has details in SharedPreferences.
3. Connects to socket if not connected before.
4. If user has details, starts loading and in the first step it makes isLoadingUserForMain = false so that until it loads and gets responds it won't be able to call.

Please tell me your opinion thanks..

Comment: It is not recommended to have pictures of your code in the question. Please paste your code in and wrap it in three backticks (`) on each end. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the best way of doing what you want to achieve is...

1. Make an Splash or middle screen of loading.
2. push all the asynchronous task at that Widget.
3. You can handle anything there.

It is not recommended to do asynchronous tasks in main function. So you need to make Material app to do the tasks..

Answer (score 1):

I would have a splash screen like @Akash mentions, but I would call these methods when your provider is initialized. For example, lets say you create your providers like this at the top of your app:

```
runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
  Provider<DatabaseService>(
    create: (_) => YourService(),
    lazy: false,
  ),
  ], 
  child: MyApp()));
```

Your init logic in the question would exist in the constructor of `YourService`.

Now you could have a stream of `userDetails` that your splash screen will listen to and once it emits details go to the appropriate screen.